# Image cropping isn't working correctly when using Offload Media

Tags: theme-development, images, theme-customizer

I've been working on a custom theme using the blankslate boilerplate & I'm happy with how it performs with a few minor details. This one concerns image cropping when a site uses the Offload Media plugin & has the remove files from server setting enabled. I've spoken with the OM folks a bit & they're helpful but at the end of the day if their plugin isn't causing any problems they're not there to troubleshoot my theme, which I understand.

**My question is how can I modify my code to delay sending the file to the S3 bucket until the customizer has had a chance to crop & place the image?**

My code is below & I appreciate any advice!

```
    // Some picture
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'some_setting',
        array(
            'default' => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr',
        )
        );

        $wp_customize->add_section('some_section', array(
            'title' => __('Some Picture', 'textdomain'),
            'priority' => 10,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'some_setting', array(
            'label'    => __( 'Some Picture', 'textdomain' ),
            'section' => 'title_tagline',
            'height'      => 250,
            'width'       => 250,
            'flex-width'  => false,
            'flex-height' => false,
            'settings' => 'some_setting',
            'transport' => 'refresh'

        ) ) );
```

Comment: It was actually painfully simple to fix this, I needed to change ```WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control``` to ```WP_Customize_Media_Control```, add in the mime type, & define the thumbnail to call. Many thanks to OM's own Ian for providing guidance!

Comment: You could formulate this into an answer and accept it for future reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aye, it's best if I adhere to policies - as I mentioned in my comment, the fix was painfully obvious updating the provided code to the following & then calling for set image sizes, even if I then had to first define the image sizes, resolved the issue:

```
// Some picture
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'some_setting',
        array(
            'default' => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr',
        )
        );

        $wp_customize->add_section('some_section', array(
            'title' => __('Some Picture', 'textdomain'),
            'priority' => 10,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Media_Control( $wp_customize, 'some_setting', array(
            'label'    => __( 'Some Picture', 'textdomain' ),
            'section' => 'title_tagline',
            'height'      => 250,
            'width'       => 250,
            'flex-width'  => false,
            'flex-height' => false,
            'settings' => 'some_setting',
            'mime_type' => 'image',
            'transport' => 'refresh'

        ) ) );
```